# how do i use cakephp 2.2 jshelper to call other jshelper functions?

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have the following code:

```
$this->Js->get('#get_meters_today')->event('click',
    $this->Js->request(
        array('action' => 'getMetersToday'),
        array('async' => true, 'update' => '#meters_today')
    )
);

$this->Html->scriptBlock(
    $this->Js->domReady(
        $this->Js->request(
            array('action' => 'getMetersToday'),
            array('async' => true, 'update' => '#meters_today')
        )
    ), array('inline' => false)
);
```

what I want to do is just have the `Js->request` written once and referred to by the `click` method and the `domReady` method. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: IMO it's a lot easier to write the jQuery scripts by hand and only use the JsHelper to add them to the buffer. This way you have much more control over your Javascript and it's easier to debug

Comment: I also think that using the JsHelper is horrible practice, which usually makes things harder than they should be.